# firestore rest api permission denied

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm using Writebatch `https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/my_project_link/documents:batchWrite`with `Authorization` header as `Bearer my_token` and in my security rules inside the console i have these rules

```html
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write, delete, update, create: if(request.auth != null || request.auth == null)
      && request.time < timestamp.date(2020, 12, 12);
    }
```

but it respond with

```html
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Missing or insufficient permissions.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

I don't know what's missing or maybe it's an issue with the firebase

But when i use google OAuth2.0 credentials it works

Comment: Are you authenticated when you attempt a read?

Comment: @Jay i'm using rest api in android so after i generate my token using `firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getIdToken(true)` i put the token inside the `Authorization` header as Bearer my_token

Comment: Can I ask how do you testing this?

Comment: @vitooh i use firefox `restclient` extension